# How to do a Second Commit in Github

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

Can anybody explain how can use github to store my project. I have created an account,created a repository, uploaded my files to it all these are done mechanically by following their help.  But i dont know what to do next. How can i do a second commit.
and what is mean by branch please explain it as to a beginner i am not understanding their help too.

Comment: Have you tried reading a Git tutorial, such as the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/)?

Comment: There an official guide for that.

Comment: can anybody explain it two or three steps what i have to do to do a second commit from computer

Comment: Yes, the Git Community Book can. ;) See the [Normal Workflow](http://book.git-scm.com/3_normal_workflow.html) section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/) is a great resource for learning all about git, from basic usage right up to really advanced stuff.

If for some reason that's not to your liking, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) links to a large number of reference guides for using git. You may want to look at the "beginner's references" section. Also some answers to that question point to GUI tools for Git that you may find useful.

The basic commands you're going to need to learn to use git effectively include `add`, `status`, `diff`, `commit`, `pull`, `push`, `checkout`, `merge`, and `branch`. You can get basic help for each command by using `git help` followed by the command you need help for (e.g. `git help add`).